# comparing string with hash(#) to database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have aa update query like this-

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$q = $qb->update('Entities\SocialKeyword', 'u')
->set('u.published', '?1')
->where('u.eventId = ?2')
->andwhere('u.hashtag = ?3')
->setParameter(1,$this->published)
->setParameter(2,$this->event_id)
->setParameter(3,$this->hashtag)
->getQuery();
$p = $q->execute();
```

I have a column 'hashtag' in my database.

When I am comparing a string like-abcdefgh its working fine but when I compare a string with hash(#) like this - #abcdefgh its not working .

I'm passing these all parameter from URL like this-

serve.shows/index.php/twitter/add_keyword?event_id=33889&hashtag=#ijklmnopqaasd&published=1

When I am using '%23' instead of '#' its also not working.

So how can I compare a string with hash-tag.

Comment: Using a GET param like ?hashtag=#foo won't work as the hashtag param will have a "" value. The # indicates that you want to browse to the #foo anchor tag.

Comment: The problem is that the hashtag(#) is interpreted as a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and it's not passed to the server... you will need to encode the hashtag to a different value

Comment: Are you URL decoding first?

Comment: is any alternate to do that..?

Comment: whats the output of `echo $this->hashtag;`?

Comment: now its working fine, the thing i was missing to encode all the special charactor like '+' in the string.thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'it's not working', what exactly do you mean?

What is stored in the database? the hashtag with or without the '#' character?

You may need to urldecode (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) all the incoming parameters prior to comparing.

Comment: string stored in database is with hashtag and without hashtag both.